# can we configure oozie coordinator which will trigger when data is available in two different directories?

Tags: oozie

I would like create oozie coordinator which will be depending on five different input folders once data available in these folders then it should trigger job. Is it possible?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please add details of what you have tried so far to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can perform the same by calling some UDF Jar, which will help to check the Input Location defined in the Mention configuration and will exist with exception if the List of Input Location is empty